# Get first cell in a row using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the first few lines of my code:

```
$('tr.existing_users > td').click(function(e){

    var target_name= e.target;
    var first_element=target_name.parent.first; //wrong
```

`e.target` gives me a `td` which is wrapped in a `tr`. I want to read the `innerHTML` of the **first element** in that `tr` row. How do I do this? (I'm also interested in jQuery solutions of course)

Answer (score 2):

```
var first_element = $(this).parent().children().eq(0);
var first_html = first_element.html();
```

Comment: It works with `.html()` at the end. Thanks. I found this the most practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.existing_users').on("click", function(e){  //listen for click on tr
    console.log($(this).find("> td").eq(0).html());  //find children tds and get first one
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(e.target).closest('tr').children().first().html();
```

This solution keeps your existing click selector and will always give you the html of the first element within the first parent `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) along with [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('tr.existing_users > td').click(function(e){
    var first_element =  $(this).closest('tr').find(':eq(0)').html();
});
```