# How to select first td compared to the clicked td

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

It should be very easy if the selector was just `<tr>` like this `$('tr')`, but I target `td`. For example click here or `td` 2 etc. I want to have the content of the first `td` compared to the clicked `td`. That is to say `td` 1 in this case.

```js
//And this is my jQuery code with <tr> .. what about if a select was a <td> ? 
$('tr').on('click', function() {
  var tds = $('td:first-child', this).text();
  alert(tds);
});

//After having documented I found this but that did not help :( 
var td1 = $(this).closest('td.id').prev('').text();
alert(td1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="id"> td 1 </td>
    <td> td 2 </td>
    <td> td 3 </td>
    <td> CLICK HERE </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use backticks to do inline code markup, so you don't have to do things like < tr >. Instead, do `<tr>` (that's <tr> with backticks around it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first cell in a row using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069769/get-first-cell-in-a-row-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank you :) I did not know how to do it .. thank you for showing me this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuerys [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) functions:

```
$('td').on('click',function()
  {
     var tr = $(this).parent();
     var tds = tr.children();
     var first_td = tds[0];
     var text = $(first_td).text();
     alert(text);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you ! it works too :)
I must say that this is the kind of my code :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the first `td` of any clicked row use the `:first` selector, like this:

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {
  var tds = $(this).find('td:first').text();
});
```

Alternatively, if the `click` event is bound to the `td` itself, use `closest()` to get the parent `tr`, then find the first `td`:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
  var tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! it works :) 
this is my first time I use the method closest()